# How to populate value in selectbox using angularjs with same ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I have two select box div for gettting scoredetails home teams and awayteams first and second innings

These two div are come in tabs only

So i need same ng-model in both innings for code reusing.but when i am using my browser will hang

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.homePlayers = [{
    "id": "586150f2d99139510b4254bb",
    "name": "Sachin Tendulkar",
    "country": "India"
}, {
    "id": "586150f2d99139510b4254b1",
    "name": "Saurav Ganguly",
    "country": "India"
}];

$scope.awayPlayers =
[{
    "id": "586150f2d99139510b4254b2",
    "name": "Shane Watson",
    "country": "Aus"
}, {
    "id": "586150f2d99139510b4254b3",
    "name": "Steve Waugh",
    "country": "Aus"
}];

});
```

this is my html content how to populate

```
<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

India bat vs Aus bowl<br>
    <div class="row">
        <select ng-model="battingDetail.batterId">
            <option ng-repeat="item in homePlayers" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</option>
        </select> <select ng-model="bowlingDetail.bowlerId">
            <option ng-repeat="item in awayPlayers" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</option>
        </select>
        <a ng-click="submitScores('hometeam')">UPDATE SCORE</a>
    </div>

Aus bat vs India bowl<br>
    <div class="row">
        <select ng-model="battingDetail.batterId">
            <option ng-repeat="item in awayPlayers" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</option>
        </select> <select ng-model="bowlingDetail.bowlerId">
            <option ng-repeat="item in homePlayers" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</option>
        </select>
        <a ng-click="submitScores('awayteam')">UPDATE SCORE</a>
    </div>

</body>
```

I have two select box div for gettting scoredetails home teams and awayteams first and second innings

These two div are not come in same page in my webpage tabs only.But when i am using this way ny browser will hang.

So i need same ng-model in both innings for code reusing.but when i am using my browser will hang

Comment: Does it crash when you try to submit the scores? If so, could you add that code aswell?

Comment: @BasPauw When changing the selectbox value it will crash

Comment: @BasPauw can you help why it is happening

Comment: Looks like it works just fine if I make a plunker for it. https://plnkr.co/edit/qT7wlEc2q6jDkp2stZVw?p=info

Comment: Do you get any errors in the log?

Comment: @BasPauw see when i select first India bat Aus bowl then I select Aus bat India bowl that field is previous innings is missing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132411/discussion-between-bas-pauw-and-aravi-s).